# How do remove backslahes from strings

Tags: ruby

I have a string:
"(128 (31) (J (C (\(C\) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))" "(64 (30) ($ 40))"

The backslashes are part of the string, they print and everything

How can I remove the backslashes using ruby 2.1.5 with debian 8 linux?

Comment: `#delete('\\')`

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could have figured this out on your own, but nevertheless:

```
str = '"(128 (31) (J (C (\(C\) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))" "(64 (30) ($ 40))"'
puts str.delete("\\")
# => "(128 (31) (J (C ((C) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))" "(64 (30) ($ 40))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are tricky.

They must be escaped even in single quoted strings. So `\\` is a single backslash and should always be written that way. Ruby is just forgiving with your malformatted string.

Try either of these

```
str.delete("\\")
str.delete('\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "(128 (31) (J (C (\(C\) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))" "(64 (30) ($ 40))"
```

1) method **:tr**

```
puts str.tr("\\", "")
# => "(128 (31) (J (C ((C) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))(64 (30) ($ 40))"
```

2) method **:delete**

```
puts str.delete("\\")
# => "(128 (31) (J (C ((C) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))(64 (30) ($ 40))"
```

3) method **:gsub**

```
puts str.gsub("\\", "")
# => "(128 (31) (J (C ((C) D 0 0 NIL NIL))) ($ 54))(64 (30) ($ 40))"
```